# Highlighting the search list isn't working (jquery issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created few unordered lists and a search bar above them. Now I want that as soon as I enter any letter (which is already existing in my list with the letter begining in it) in the search bar it should highlight the whole word or the line. I wrote code for them but its not working. I am following this [tutorial](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=32&video=18076)

**index.php class**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My site</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
   </head>

   <body>
      <p><input id="search" type="text"/></p>

      <ul id="names">
         <li>cat girl</li>
         <li>dog man</li>
         <li>rat kid</li>
         <li>bird boy</li>
      </ul>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/select.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

**select.js class:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#search').keyup()(function(){
      var search=$(this).val();
      $("#names li:contains('"+search+ "')").addClass('highlight');
   });
});
```

**style.css class**

```
ul{
   list-style:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
.highlight{
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Check to make sure jquery and your script are being loaded successfully. And please give a better description of the issue than "not working". Is your developer console open? Any errors?

Comment: This is incorrect: `$('#search').keyup()(function(){`. Should be `$('#search').keyup(function(){`

Comment: @cookie monster , yah. alright now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You messed up your closure.

`.keyup()(function()` is wrong.

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $("#names li:contains('" + search + "')").addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ7XS/

Update, you should also read this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/

Comment: a thank you is more than enough ;). Have a great day. When you like the answer you can hit the "check" icon to accept it.